# Using MockBean in Micronaut with lambda runtime for Lambda Application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mockito, micronaut

I have a simple Micronaut Lambda Application and am having difficulty in successfully getting Mocks injected in to my unit tests.

build.gradle

```
micronaut {
    runtime("lambda")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    ...
}
```

With the following basic Controller

```java
@Controller
public class MyController{

  Service service;

  @Inject
  public Controller controller(Service service){
    this.service = service;
  }
 
  @Post("/test")
  public void someEndpoint(){
    service.doSomething();
  }
}
```

And the following test class:

```java
@MicronautLambdaTest
public class MyControllerTest{

  @Inject
  Service service;

  @Inject
  @Client("/")
  RxHttpClient rxHttpClient;
  
  @MockBean(Service.class)
  Service service() {       
    return mock(Service.class);
  }

  @Test
  void should_do_something_when_something(){
    rxHttpClient.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.POST("/test",""));
    verify(service, times(1)).doSomething();
  }
}
```

The test above will fail as the mock is never interacted with.

When debugging I can see that the `Service` is mocked in the test class itself, but in the `MyController` class there is an actual object being used.

I notice that when I am not using `runtime("lambda")` (e.g. `runtime("netty")`) this works as expected, so I think this is something to do with the Lambda runtime, and am hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 3):

When using `runtime("lambda")`, you need to start the test using your handler class and remove the `@MicronautTest`.

```
MicronautLambdaHandler handler = new MicronautLambdaHandler();
```

This will start the application context.

You can also pass arguments using ApplicationContext.builder()

```
ApplicationContextBuilder config = ApplicationContext.builder()
                .environments("test");
MicronautLambdaHandler handler = new MicronautLambdaHandler(config);
```

Running the test with `@MicronautTest` and `runtime("lambda")` runs two set of environment separately that's why I removed the `@MicronautTest`.

If you still want to mock classes. You can create a mock class and annotate it with `@Replaces(ClassToMock.class)` and `@Requires`.
For me it's `@Requires(env = Environment.TEST)`.

For classes that is not an implementation of an interface, you need to extend the class you want to mock (I'm using v2.5.6).

```
@Replaces(ClassToMock.class)
@Requires(env = Environment.TEST)
@Singleton
public class MockClass extends ClassToMock {

   @Override
   public void someMethod() {}
}
```

For classes that implements an interface, you can simply create another implementation and annotate it likewise.